# jsPDF is not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I imported jsPDF library and tried to export to PDF but I am getting JavaScript error jsPDF is not defined.

I tried other similar posts and it didn't work for me.

I got the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/aybhvf8e/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>

$( document ).ready(function() {

var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
})

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});


<div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your code seems correct but some issue with cdn. I have used debug one here.

Here is one working example I created which you can refer. If you don't see pdf downloading due to stackoverflow restriction, use this fiddle to test.

[Working Download PDF demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpf76o0r/)

The cdn link I used is : [JsPDF CDN LINK](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js) . You can definitely look for any other versions available.

```js
function createPdf() {

  var doc = new jsPDF();
  
  source = $('#content')[0];
  
  specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
            return true
        }
    };
  
  doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15, 
    {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    }
  );
  doc.save('sample-file.pdf')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content">
     <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>

    <p>A paragraph</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button onclick="javascript:createPdf()" id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

For me only this could solve the problem 'jsPDF is not defined - `const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF()`, as it's shown in the simple example below

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.4.0/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script>
  <title>Convert <div> to PDF</title>
</head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
        </div>

        <button onclick="generatePDF()">Generate PDF</button>

        <script>
        function generatePDF() {
        // Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using millimeters for units
        **const doc = new jspdf.jsPDF();**

        doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
        doc.save("a4.pdf");
        }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two main issues, solved in this [fork](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljnya5gp/1/). First, you did not link to `jspdf`. You can do that in the html code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

Second, you add the `click` event listener outside the `ready()` function. This, in turn, causes two problems: the event may not be attached (make sure you check the reason for the `ready()` function) and the variables that you define in the `ready()` function are not available (get out of scope) in the `click` function. You can fix both problems by setting the `click` listener inside the `ready` listener:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};
$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});

})
```

Answer (score 0):

VQR ..... one question, my app works some times on places without network, so the next line won't be work without network , correct?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

So, I installed it ...

```
npm install jspdf --save
```

But now, what files have I to copy to my Js carpet to works the line ?

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
```